# Running sidekiq gives "Segmentation fault" error on Ubuntu 14.04 running Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu

Whenever I try to run sidekiq with this command

`$ bundle exec sidekiq`

I get this error:

`/home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@somename/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:9: [BUG] Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

I am using:

Rails: `3.1.11`

Ruby: `1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-linux]`

Ubuntu: `14.04.2 LTS`

Sidekiq: `~> 2.15.2`

Any help to resolve the issue will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting your answer

Answer (score 0):

i got this segmentation fault on my production server with similar configuration.i spent a lot of time to understand why is this error coming and what does it mean.BUT at the end,i ended up removing few unused gems from `gemfile` which removed this error.You can give it a try too.

Comment: all of the gems in my Gemfile are in use.